# SELECT specific date with JOIN

Tags: mysql

Table `Client` contains `last_name` and `email` column while table `Product` contain `email` and `expiry_date` column with `13 row of records`. This syntax correctly select only 2 rows from `Product` table.

```
SELECT * FROM `Product` WHERE expiry_date > DATE_ADD( CURRENT_DATE, INTERVAL 24 DAY ) 
AND expiry_date < DATE_ADD( CURRENT_DATE, INTERVAL 24 + 1 DAY )
```

Now  I want to join it with `Client` table to select `last_name` with matching `email`. Unfortunately my `JOIN` syntax below select all 13 records from `Product` table.

```
SELECT * FROM `Product` JOIN `Client`
ON product.email=client.email
AND (expiry_date > DATE_ADD( CURRENT_DATE, INTERVAL 24 DAY ) 
AND expiry_date < DATE_ADD( CURRENT_DATE, INTERVAL 24 + 1 DAY ))
```

This syntax also does not work. All 13 rows from `Product` table was selected:

```
SELECT * FROM
(
SELECT * FROM `Product` WHERE expiry_date > DATE_ADD( CURRENT_DATE, INTERVAL 24 DAY ) 
AND expiry_date < DATE_ADD( CURRENT_DATE, INTERVAL 24 +1 DAY )
) A
LEFT JOIN Client ON A.email=client.email
WHERE A.expiry_date > DATE_ADD( CURRENT_DATE, INTERVAL 24 DAY ) 
AND A.expiry_date < DATE_ADD( CURRENT_DATE, INTERVAL 24 +1 DAY )
```

How do I select only 2 `last_name` and not all 13. I hope I explained it clearly. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Maybe it will help if you provide sample data..

Answer (score 0):

The way you are specifying your JOIN conditions, everything matches. You should specify a WHERE clause instead

```
SELECT * FROM `Product` JOIN `Client`
ON product.email=client.email
WHERE expiry_date > DATE_ADD( CURRENT_DATE, INTERVAL 24 DAY ) 
   AND expiry_date < DATE_ADD( CURRENT_DATE, INTERVAL 24 + 1 DAY )
```

Comment: Still same, I've got 13 row and not 2.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `GROUP BY` to get only 2 rows instead of all rows in `Product` table. For example:

```
SELECT * FROM `Product` JOIN `Client`
ON product.email=client.email
AND (expiry_date > DATE_ADD( CURRENT_DATE, INTERVAL 24 DAY ) 
AND expiry_date < DATE_ADD( CURRENT_DATE, INTERVAL 24 + 1 DAY )) 
GROUP BY expiry_date
```